# Checkout Information in custom mail

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

How to get Checkout Information in custom mail

```
   /* Get Information For Un support Email to Admin */
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();        
        //$name = $customer->getName();
        $email = $customer->getEmail();

        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $productName = array();
        /*$skus = array();*/
            foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $productName[] = $item->getProduct()->getName();
                /*$skus[] = $item->getProduct()->getSku();*/
            }       
        $productNames = implode(', ', $productName);
        /*$productSkus = implode(', ', $skus);*/
        $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $grandTotal = 0;
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $total += $item->getPriceInclTax() * $item->getQty();
        }

        $checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
         $billAddress = $checkout->getBillingAddress();

         Mage::log($billAddress->getData());
          //you can get contact number in that
         $tele = $billAddress->getTelephone();
         $add = $billAddress->getCity();
         $street = $billAddress->getStreet1();
         $state = $billAddress->getRegion();
        $name = $billAddress->getName();

 $template_id = 'my_custom_email';
    // Who were sending to...
       $email_to = 'mymail@gmail.com';
    //$email_to = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
    //$email_to = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email');
    $customer_name   = $name;
    // Load our template by template_id
    $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);

    $custom_variable = $name;
    $custom_variable1 = $email;
    $custom_variable2 = $postCode;
    $custom_variable3 = $productNames;
    $custom_variable4 = $tele;
    $custom_variable5 = $total;
    $custom_variable6 = $add;
    $custom_variable7 = $street;
    $custom_variable8 = $state;



    $email_template_variables = array(
        'custom_variable' => $custom_variable,
        'custom_variable1' => $custom_variable1,
        'custom_variable2' => $custom_variable2,
        'custom_variable3' => $custom_variable3,
        'custom_variable4' => $custom_variable4,
        'custom_variable5' => $custom_variable5,
        'custom_variable6' => $custom_variable6,
        'custom_variable7' => $custom_variable7,
        'custom_variable8' => $custom_variable8,


    );
    $sender_name = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_STORE_STORE_NAME);
    $sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
    $email_template->setSenderName($sender_name);
    $email_template->setSenderEmail($sender_email);    
    $email_template->send($email_to, $customer_name, $email_template_variables);
```

Comment: Can you please tel l me when you want to fire this email?

Comment: After Place order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kothari,for your can use `Magento Event/observer.`

Call observer at event `checkout_submit_all_after`

At this observer ,you *can get Order Object* from *`$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()`*.

**config.xml code:**

```
<global>
<events>
        <checkout_submit_all_after>
            <observers>
                <myaction_save_order>
                    <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>SendCustomOrderEmail</method>
                </myaction_save_order>
            </observers>
        </checkout_submit_all_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

**Observer code:**

```
<?php 

class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer{
    public function SendCustomOrderEmail($observer){

        $order=$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $name = $order->getCustomerFirstname();
        $email = $order->getCustomerEmail();


        $productName = array();
        /*$skus = array();*/
            foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                $productName[] = $item->getName();
                /*$skus[] = $item->getProduct()->getSku();*/
            }       
        $productNames = implode(', ', $productName);
        /*$productSkus = implode(', ', $skus);*/

        $total = 0;
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $total += $item->getPriceInclTax() * $item->getQty();
        }


         $billAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();

         //Mage::log($billAddress->getData());
          //you can get contact number in that
         $tele = $billAddress->getTelephone();
         $add = $billAddress->getCity();
         $street = $billAddress->getStreet1();
         $state = $billAddress->getRegion();
        $name = $billAddress->getName();

        $template_id = 'my_custom_email';
        // Who were sending to...
           $email_to = 'mymail@gmail.com';
        //$email_to = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
        //$email_to = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email');
        $customer_name   = $name;
        // Load our template by template_id
        $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);

        $custom_variable = $name;
        $custom_variable1 = $email;
        $custom_variable2 = $postCode;
        $custom_variable3 = $productNames;
        $custom_variable4 = $tele;
        $custom_variable5 = $total;
        $custom_variable6 = $add;
        $custom_variable7 = $street;
        $custom_variable8 = $state;



        $email_template_variables = array(
            'custom_variable' => $custom_variable,
            'custom_variable1' => $custom_variable1,
            'custom_variable2' => $custom_variable2,
            'custom_variable3' => $custom_variable3,
            'custom_variable4' => $custom_variable4,
            'custom_variable5' => $custom_variable5,
            'custom_variable6' => $custom_variable6,
            'custom_variable7' => $custom_variable7,
            'custom_variable8' => $custom_variable8,


        );
        $sender_name = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_STORE_STORE_NAME);
        $sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
        /* add by AB */
        $email_template->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);
        $email_template->setSenderName($adminUsername);
        $email_template->setSenderEmail($adminEmail);
        $email_template->send($customer->getEmail(),$Username,$emailTempVariables);    
        /* add by AB */


    }

}
```

**NOte that code is not test.I have put  this code basic of idea**